# mod_rewrite get remaining query string parameters without matching them in the pattern

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am extremely new to RewriteRules so I am not sure if this is possible, is there any way of having my second query string parameter be passed to my RewriteRule without me having to specify it in the RegEx pattern?

The reason I ask is because I would like my URL to display as

```
http://mysite/Pumps/PumpID01
```

Opposed to

```
http://mysite.com/pumps/product.php?id=PumpID&s=Category
```

The current rewrite rule I am using is:

```
RewriteRule ^Pumps/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/?$ pumps/product.php?id=$1&s= [NC,L,QSA]
```

If I specify 's' in the substituion then the page renders correctly. However 's' can be one of an expanding total of categories.

How would I go about passing the value of 's' dynamically?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the possible values of "s" are. How would one know what to pass for "s"?  Is it "Pumps" in your example?

Comment: Hi Matt, sorry I should have been more clear the value of "s" is passed to the URL via a get variable on the pumps page, it can be of value "INTERMITTENT", "CONTINUOUS" or "WELLSERVICE"

Comment: I'm still not clear on how the system would know what to pass for "s".  Maybe you need a RewriteMap to handle the full list of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to have `category` identifier in the pretty URL as:

```
 http://mysite/Pumps/INTERMITTENT/PumpID01
```

If you agree then this rewrite rule should work:

```
 RewriteRule ^Pumps/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ pumps/product.php?id=$2&s=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That would be a great solution, Thank-You!

Comment: May I ask what (\w+) means as an expression?

Comment: `\w+` is shortcut for `([A-Za-z0-9_]+)` if you want hyphen also then let me edit my answer.

Comment: Ok edited it to make `([\w-]+)` which is same as `([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)`

Comment: Ahh I thought it would be an abbreviation of some sort, thanks again.